# How to automate open office online apps

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, openoffice-api

I need to automate excel online functionality that is being used by a web app. How can I automate excel online (open office app integrated with my web app)?  I'm using selenium for my web app..

Comment: What you want and what you try

Comment: I have not tried anything. I'm looking for a solution to automating excel online. My web app launches open office excel. I need to select enter data